# Ajax GET request of URL fails, but hurl.it GET request of same URL works. What gives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, web-scraping

I'm trying to access the contents of a web page as part of the functionality of a javascript Chrome extension I'm creating and have encountered a bit of a puzzle.

When accessing the resource as part of an Ajax GET request in my extension's script, the resource does not correctly load. When I attempt the same GET request through [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) (with follow-redirects on and no header modifications), the data loads. It also works if I just enter the URL in my browser.

I can't figure out what hurl.it is doing differently in its request and how to fix my own.

The URL I'm trying to query is in the form of (with 'Hello' as an example search):

http://overdrive.dclibrary.org/BANGSearch.dll?Type=FullText&PerPage=24&URL=SearchResults.htm&Sort=SortBy%3DRelevancy&FullTextField=All&FullTextCriteria=Hello&x=0&y=0%22

This would appear in my script like:

```
var get_url = "http://overdrive.dclibrary.org/BANGSearch.dll?Type=FullText&PerPage=24&URL=SearchResults.htm&Sort=SortBy%3DRelevancy&FullTextField=All&FullTextCriteria=Hello&x=0&y=0"

$.get(get_url,function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

To be clear, the above code *will* output HTML to the console. It just doesn't include any of the results from the search query.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My extension has been given permission to access anything in the dclibrary.org domain.

Comment: Are you getting bit by CORS?

Comment: works for me. it returns a whole HTML page with a bunch of ugly javascript a 4th grader would write if they knew syntax. Additionally, it is quite amateurish to have .dll in your URL. Looks like their whole API is like that.

Comment: Don't think it's a CORS issue, because I've given the extension permission to access anything in the dclibrary.org domain (added that to the post) and am successfully getting other dclibrary.org resources not in the overdrive.dclibrary.org subdomain. Then again, this is my first javascript outing.

Comment: Just want to emphasize that I do get HTML returned, but if you search that for 'Hello' (or whatever search term you've included) you won't find anything. If you search the output from the hurl.it request you *do* see the 'Hello' search results.

Comment: I don't see the results in hurl.it, just a bunch of html with no real content, as far as i can tell. i don't see content in fiddler directly, either.

Comment: @FlavorScape Here is what I get with hurl.it (with follow-redirects on--search for 'hello' and you should see ebook titles): https://gist.github.com/evonfriedland/2244f6181dcb2f3d052e

And this is the response from the ajax get: https://gist.github.com/evonfriedland/04d4e2be36f0e92ec426

Comment: don't see the missing results, here is gist of what i get in chrome. https://gist.github.com/vance/733b06adf0ff8dc36d3d

Comment: @FlavorScape by 'in chrome' do you mean when you enter the URL in the browser? If so, I'm not having any issue with that. The response with 'missing results' is what I get when I add the code (included above) to my extension's script. Don't have enough reputation to move this to chat..

Answer (score 0):

There's a redirect in the response, which can break a browser.  HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily works in chrome though. why is it returning a 302 response? With ASP.net/IIS sometimes unauthorized (not logged in) users are redirected with a 302 response. This is bad behavior, if login is needed, it should issue a 403, but obviously this is not the intent.

Use Fiddler to debug full headers (or chrome dev tools).

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://overdrive.dclibrary.org/4F2C56FC-9659-4640-9E00-9433B3CC9A7F/10/50/en/SearchResults.htm?searchid=38432201s&sortby=Relevancy
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: Session=4F2C56FC-9659-4640-9E00-9433B3CC9A7F|0|0|50|en; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2030 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 20:53:31 GMT
Content-Length: 12484
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: 60
Via: HTTP/1.1 proxy2444

<html><head><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"ad9513338b","applicationID":"2495152,2495041","transactionName":"MVBbNkcACBADUU1QWggafQ1BLwMXIV1XTUcJWVUHR04kAgxVaVhSAxpwDFEEHg==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":61,"ttGuid":"1260BAD900521DF4","agent":"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-593.min.js"}</script><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VwIAVVRbGwEEXVRTAgM="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o?o:e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({QJf3ax:[function(t,e){function n(t){function e(e,n,a){t&&t(e,n,a),a||(a={});for(var c=s(e),f=c.length,u=i(a,o,r),d=0;f>d;d++)c[d].apply(u,n);return u}function a(t,e){f[t]=s(t).concat(e)}function s(t){return f[t]||[]}function c(){return n(e)}var f={};return{on:a,emit:e,create:c,listeners:s,_events:f}}function r(){return{}}var o="nr@context",i=t("gos");e.exports=n()},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],ee:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("QJf3ax")},{}],3:[function(t){function e(t){try{i.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var n,r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i={};try{n=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"function"==typeof console.log&&(i.console=!0,-1!==n.indexOf("dev")&&(i.dev=!0),-1!==n.indexOf("nr_dev")&&(i.nrDev=!0))}catch(a){}i.nrDev&&r.on("internal-error",function(t){e(t.stack)}),i.dev&&r.on("fn-err",function(t,n,r){e(r.stack)}),i.dev&&(e("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),e("flags: "+o(i,function(t){return t}).join(", ")))},{1:20,ee:"QJf3ax"}],4:[function(t){function e(t,e,n,i,s){try{c?c-=1:r("err",[s||new UncaughtException(t,e,n)])}catch(f){try{r("ierr",[f,(new Date).getTime(),!0])}catch(u){}}return"function"==typeof a?a.apply(this,o(arguments)):!1}function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}function n(t){r("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}var r=t("handle"),o=t(6),i=t("ee"),a=window.onerror,s=!1,c=0;t("loader").features.err=!0,t(3),window.onerror=e;try{throw new Error}catch(f){"stack"in f&&(t(4),t(5),"addEventListener"in window&&t(1),window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&t(2),s=!0)}i.on("fn-start",function(){s&&(c+=1)}),i.on("fn-err",function(t,e,r){s&&(this.thrown=!0,n(r))}),i.on("fn-end",function(){s&&!this.thrown&&c>0&&(c-=1)}),i.on("internal-error",function(t){r("ierr",[t,(new Date).getTime(),!0])})},{1:5,2:8,3:3,4:7,5:6,6:21,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],5:[function(t,e){function n(t){i.inPlace(t,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",r)}function r(t){return t[1]}var o=(t(1),t("ee").create()),i=t(2)(o),a=t("gos");if(e.exports=o,n(window),"getPrototypeOf"in Object){for(var s=document;s&&!s.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)s=Object.getPrototypeOf(s);s&&n(s);for(var c=XMLHttpRequest.prototype;c&&!c.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)c=Object.getPrototypeOf(c);c&&n(c)}else XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")&&n(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);o.on("addEventListener-start",function(t){if(t[1]){var e=t[1];"function"==typeof e?this.wrapped=t[1]=a(e,"nr@wrapped",function(){return i(e,"fn-",null,e.name||"anonymous")}):"function"==typeof e.handleEvent&&i.inPlace(e,["handleEvent"],"fn-")}}),o.on("removeEventListener-start",function(t){var e=this.wrapped;e&&(t[1]=e)})},{1:21,2:22,ee:"QJf3ax",gos:"7eSDFh"}],6:[function(t,e){var n=(t(2),t("ee").create()),r=t(1)(n);e.exports=n,r.inPlace(window,["requestAnimationFrame","mozRequestAnimationFrame","webkitRequestAnimationFrame","msRequestAnimationFrame"],"raf-"),n.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=r(t[0],"fn-")})},{1:22,2:21,ee:"QJf3ax"}],7:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){var r=t[0];"string"==typeof r&&(r=new Function(r)),t[0]=o(r,"fn-",null,n)}var r=(t(2),t("ee").create()),o=t(1)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["setTimeout","setInterval","setImmediate"],"setTimer-"),r.on("setTimer-start",n)},{1:22,2:21,ee:"QJf3ax"}],8:[function(t,e){function n(){f.inPlace(this,p,"fn-")}function r(t,e){f.inPlace(e,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-")}function o(t,e){return e}function i(t,e){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}var a=t("ee").create(),s=t(1),c=t(2),f=c(a),u=c(s),d=window.XMLHttpRequest,p=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"];e.exports=a,window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var e=new d(t);try{a.emit("new-xhr",[],e),u.inPlace(e,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",function(t,e){return e}),e.addEventListener("readystatechange",n,!1)}catch(r){try{a.emit("internal-error",[r])}catch(o){}}return e},i(d,XMLHttpRequest),XMLHttpRequest.prototype=d.prototype,f.inPlace(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",o),a.on("send-xhr-start",r),a.on("open-xhr-start",r)},{1:5,2:22,ee:"QJf3ax"}],9:[function(t){function e(t){if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;if("object"!=typeof t)return void 0;if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;if("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData)return void 0;try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(e){return void 0}}function n(t){var n=this.params,r=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var i=0;c>i;i++)t.removeEventListener(s[i],this.listener,!1);if(!n.aborted){if(r.duration=(new Date).getTime()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){n.status=t.status;var a=t.responseType,f="arraybuffer"===a||"blob"===a||"json"===a?t.response:t.responseText,u=e(f);if(u&&(r.rxSize=u),this.sameOrigin){var d=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");d&&(n.cat=d.split(", ").pop())}}else n.status=0;r.cbTime=this.cbTime,o("xhr",[n,r,this.startTime])}}}function r(t,e){var n=i(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+":"+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}if(window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)){t("loader").features.xhr=!0;var o=t("handle"),i=t(2),a=t("ee"),s=["load","error","abort","timeout"],c=s.length,f=t(1);t(4),t(3),a.on("new-xhr",function(){this.totalCbs=0,this.called=0,this.cbTime=0,this.end=n,this.ended=!1,this.xhrGuids={}}),a.on("open-xhr-start",function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},r(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),a.on("open-xhr-end",function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),a.on("send-xhr-start",function(t,n){var r=this.metrics,o=t[0],i=this;if(r&&o){var f=e(o);f&&(r.txSize=f)}this.startTime=(new Date).getTime(),this.listener=function(t){try{"abort"===t.type&&(i.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||i.called===i.totalCbs&&(i.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof n.onload))&&i.end(n)}catch(e){try{a.emit("internal-error",[e])}catch(r){}}};for(var u=0;c>u;u++)n.addEventListener(s[u],this.listener,!1)}),a.on("xhr-cb-time",function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),a.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),a.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),a.on("addEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("removeEventListener-end",function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=(new Date).getTime()))}),a.on("fn-end",function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&a.emit("xhr-cb-time",[(new Date).getTime()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}},{1:"XL7HBI",2:10,3:8,4:5,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],10:[function(t,e){e.exports=function(t){var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split("://");return!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname),r.sameOrigin=!e.hostname||e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port&&e.protocol===n.protocol,r}},{}],11:[function(t,e){function n(t){return function(){r(t,[(new Date).getTime()].concat(i(arguments)))}}var r=t("handle"),o=t(1),i=t(2);"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=window.NREUM);var a=["setPageViewName","addPageAction","setCustomAttribute","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","noticeError"];o(a,function(t,e){window.NREUM[e]=n("api-"+e)}),e.exports=window.NREUM},{1:20,2:21,handle:"D5DuLP"}],gos:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("7eSDFh")},{}],"7eSDFh":[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){if(r.call(t,e))return t[e];var o=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:o,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),o}catch(i){}return t[e]=o,o}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],D5DuLP:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){return r.listeners(t).length?r.emit(t,e,n):(o[t]||(o[t]=[]),void o[t].push(e))}var r=t("ee").create(),o={};e.exports=n,n.ee=r,r.q=o},{ee:"QJf3ax"}],handle:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],XL7HBI:[function(t,e){function n(t){var e=typeof t;return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:i(t,o,function(){return r++})}var r=1,o="nr@id",i=t("gos");e.exports=n},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],id:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("XL7HBI")},{}],loader:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,e){function n(){var t=l.info=NREUM.info;if(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&f&&f.body){s(h,function(e,n){e in t||(t[e]=n)}),l.proto="https"===p.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp?"https://":"http://",a("mark",["onload",i()]);var e=f.createElement("script");e.src=l.proto+t.agent,f.body.appendChild(e)}}function r(){"complete"===f.readyState&&o()}function o(){a("mark",["domContent",i()])}function i(){return(new Date).getTime()}var a=t("handle"),s=t(1),c=(t(2),window),f=c.document,u="addEventListener",d="attachEvent",p=(""+location).split("?")[0],h={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-593.min.js"},l=e.exports={offset:i(),origin:p,features:{}};f[u]?(f[u]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),c[u]("load",n,!1)):(f[d]("onreadystatechange",r),c[d]("onload",n)),a("mark",["firstbyte",i()])},{1:20,2:11,handle:"D5DuLP"}],20:[function(t,e){function n(t,e){var n=[],o="",i=0;for(o in t)r.call(t,o)&&(n[i]=e(o,t[o]),i+=1);return n}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],21:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(0>o?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];return i}e.exports=n},{}],22:[function(t,e){function n(t){return!(t&&"function"==typeof t&&t.apply&&!t[i])}var r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i="nr@wrapper",a=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=function(t){function e(t,e,r,a){function nrWrapper(){var n,i,s,f;try{i=this,n=o(arguments),s=r&&r(n,i)||{}}catch(d){u([d,"",[n,i,a],s])}c(e+"start",[n,i,a],s);try{return f=t.apply(i,n)}catch(p){throw c(e+"err",[n,i,p],s),p}finally{c(e+"end",[n,i,f],s)}}return n(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[i]=!0,f(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function s(t,r,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<r.length;c++)s=r[c],a=t[s],n(a)||(t[s]=e(a,f?s+o:o,i,s,t))}function c(e,n,r){try{t.emit(e,n,r)}catch(o){u([o,e,n,r])}}function f(t,e){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var n=Object.keys(t);return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,{get:function(){return t[n]},set:function(e){return t[n]=e,e}})}),e}catch(r){u([r])}for(var o in t)a.call(t,o)&&(e[o]=t[o]);return e}function u(e){try{t.emit("internal-error",e)}catch(n){}}return t||(t=r),e.inPlace=s,e.flag=i,e}},{1:21,ee:"QJf3ax"}]},{},["G9z0Bl",4,9]);</script><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://overdrive.dclibrary.org/4F2C56FC-9659-4640-9E00-9433B3CC9A7F/10/50/en/SearchResults.htm?searchid=38432201s&amp;sortby=Relevancy">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```